# encode with dictionary japanese - english

Tags: dictionary, encode, non-english, cjk, kanji

I have a Japanese dictionary - English.
However, I do not understand Japanese, how it encodes!
Can anyone tell me what that is?
Thanks very much

Example :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl6Tg.png

> S”X [‚µ‚ñ‚Ì‚¤] /(n) pericardium/
>
> S”x‹@”\ [‚µ‚ñ‚Ï‚¢‚«‚Ì‚¤] /cardio-pulmonary function/
>
> S”z [‚µ‚ñ‚Ï‚¢] /(adj-na,n,vs) worry/concern/anxiety/care/(p)/
>
> S”z‚è [‚±‚±‚ë‚­‚Î‚è] /(n,vs) exerting care/attention/consideration/thoughtfulness/
>
> S”z‚ðŠ|‚¯‚é [‚µ‚ñ‚Ï‚¢‚ð‚©‚¯‚é] /(exp) to cause someone to worry/
>
> S”zŽ– [‚µ‚ñ‚Ï‚¢‚²‚Æ] /(n) worries/cares/troubles/
>
> S”z« [‚µ‚ñ‚Ï‚¢‚µ‚å‚¤] /(n) prone to worrying/
>
> S” [‚µ‚ñ‚Ï‚­] /(n) heart rate/
>
> S”²‚«Ší [‚µ‚ñ‚Ê‚«‚«] /corer/
>
> S•s‘S [‚µ‚ñ‚Ó‚º‚ñ] /(n) heart failure/

Answer (score 1):

They are not Japanese. You opened the file on your text editor with incorrect encoding. I am not 100% sure, but they might be Shift-JIS encoding Japanese are displayed as UTF-8.

If your editor has encoding switch, you may try some Japanese-supported encoding, such like SJIS, JIS, EUC-JP.